# Pandas get the combined sum of each row and colum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add the "vertical" and "horizontal" sum for each cell.

[image]

So far I've tired to get the sum of each row and column. But like this I'd have to iterate over every value and add them which seems quite inefficient.

You could combine `sum()` and `sum(1)` to create a new dataframe but then the cell in question is counted twice.

Used `df` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,3], [8,4]], columns=list("ab"))
```

Is there any simple operation to archive the wanted result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC use numpy broadcasting and subtract original DataFrame:

```
out = df.sum().to_numpy() + df.sum(1).to_numpy()[:, None] - df
print (out)
    a   b
0  12   8
1  13  15
```

Comment: @Timeless - Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly :-), should have added an MRE, sorry about that!